# Plotly: Blank choropleth map after exporting to HTML

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, choropleth

I'm trying to build an interactive, simple choropleth heatmap of all the countries in Asia. The plot displays well when in my Jupyter Notebook, but when I try to export it to html, it shows only blank.

The GeoJSON file that I'm using is [this one](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hrbrmstr/94bdd47705d05a50f9cf/raw/0ccc6b926e1aa64448e239ac024f04e518d63954/asia.geojson), it's the first result when I google *"asia geojson"*

A preview of my DataFrame file can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvJKP.png).

My code:

```py
import pandas
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=asia, locations='country', color='population', color_continuous_scale="reds", scope = 'asia', featureidkey="properties.admin", labels={'population':'Population Count'}, center={"lat": 30, "lon": 100})
fig.show()

plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='myplot.html')
```

[[Screenshot] How it looks on my Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fgCb.png)

[[Screenshot] How it looks on my web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q0JR.png)

As we can see, the .html file shows nothing when opened in my web browser. I've read the documentations and the majority of users having similar problems, yet I can't seem to make mine work.

I tried to plot the sample dataset of USA Census Data from their [official guide](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/) and it exports normally into .html, as expected.

How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: This may also be useful.`fig.write_html("myplot.html") `

Comment: @r-beginners Still not working, I'm suspecting it may be the dimensions that I plot my map in, rather than the plotly package itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code to output to html format. The geojson file you are using is associated with the data used on the [official plotly website](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#choropleth-map-using-geojson), and saved in an html file. My environment is jupyterLab 2.2.0 to check the file saving.
Data for some countries is not shown, but if you replace it with your own data, it should be fine.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hrbrmstr/94bdd47705d05a50f9cf/raw/0ccc6b926e1aa64448e239ac024f04e518d63954/asia.geojson') as response:
    asia = json.load(response)

import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=asia,
                    locations='iso_alpha',
                    color='pop',
                    color_continuous_scale="reds",
                    scope = 'asia',
                    featureidkey="properties.sov_a3",
                    labels={'population':'Population Count'},
                    center={"lat": 30, "lon": 100})

fig.show()
fig.write_html("myplot.html")
```

[image]

Comment: This worked wonders! I just substituted the df used in your example with my own DataFrame. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try this.

I have imported plotly offline as pyo and ran your fig via pyo.plot() which outputs an html file to the dir of your notebook.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hrbrmstr/94bdd47705d05a50f9cf/raw/0ccc6b926e1aa64448e239ac024f04e518d63954/asia.geojson') as response:
    asia = json.load(response)

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.offline as pyo
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007")

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=asia,
                    locations='iso_alpha',
                    color='pop',
                    color_continuous_scale="reds",
                    scope = 'asia',
                    featureidkey="properties.sov_a3",
                    labels={'population':'Population Count'},
                    center={"lat": 30, "lon": 100})

fig.show()
pyo.plot(fig)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion!

But I don't know how to make use of the div output in my Jupyter Notebook, and I haven't been able to follow the steps of which your thread has. Can you probably make it more elaborate as I'm not well-versed in Javascript and/or Flask? I just wanted to output the html without having any apps attached in.

Cheers :)

Comment: Ok, you need to run your fig via plotly offline's .plot() method. This works to generate an html in the directory of your (presumably) jupyter notebook. Please let me know if this works, it worked for me. (editing main post)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will try it for the next continent scope I'm working on :)

Comment: Welcome! If it works then please accept the reply as an answer or comment here with whatever the issue is :)